# Switch list view in promoted links webpart

Tags: 2013, list-view, promoted-links

does anybody know how I can directly switch the list view in the promoted links webpart?

Is it possible to attach an e.G. `js-link` to create a navigation above the tiles, maybe three custom buttons to switch the views?

I created three tileviews, but now I want the option to switch between those.

[image]

I also tried using [TopSPTabs.js](http://www.topsharepoint.com/dynamic-bootstrap-tabs-for-sharepoint) but if I use that all webparts on the page are wrapped inside of the tabbed content editor. I only want the different tile views of my promoted links app inside.

Also I **main issue** is, that it only works in team sites for me. I need it in a publishing page but there I only can see the tabs when I am in Edit-Mode for the page. If I save the page the tabs are gone. MDS is deactivated.

Is there a real working solution for tabs somewhere? (SP2013 on-prem)
Or does anyone have an idea how I can do that?

**EDIT:** I tried now [hillbilly tabs](http://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/), but they are also only working in team sites. Not in my publishing pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finished part 1 of 2 for my solution.

The essentials of part 1 are, if you want to get more than one tile view from promoted links you have to create a new view and click on **Custom View in SharePoint Designer**.

[image]

If you want to see the full part 1 blog post you can check out the german or english versions here:

[Multiple tile view and list tabs 1 of 2 (en)](https://afrait.com/blog/multiple-tile-view-and-list-tabs-1-of-2-en/)

[Multiple tile view and list tabs 1 of 2 (de)](https://afrait.com/blog/multiple-tile-view-and-list-tabs-1-of-2-de/)

**Part 2 is now online**.

Again the essentials here: I used the [TopSPTabsNoBS.js](http://www.topsharepoint.com/dynamic-bootstrap-tabs-for-sharepoint) from TopSharePoint.com and with that I was able to get great tabs. Note: It is important to set each webpart in the chrome typ to "title only"

[image]

Endresult looks like that:

[image]

Hope this answer is okay and don't get's downvoted again.

If you want to see the full part 2 blog post you can check out the german or english versions here:

[Multiple tile view and list tabs 2 of 2 (en)](https://afrait.com/blog/multiple-tile-view-and-list-tabs-2-of-2-en/)

[Multiple tile view and list tabs 2 of 2 (de)](https://afrait.com/blog/multiple-tile-view-and-list-tabs-2-of-2-de/)

Answer (score 1):

Add all the needed list view web parts on the page and put them in tabs using jQuery.

See below link for putting web parts inside tabs.
http://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/

EDIT: I see you tried the tabs solution with TopSPTabs.js. Can you explain little more on what issue you are facing with that? Does it not work with list view web parts?

Comment: edited my question. Hope it is clearer. I only want my promoted link app views inside of the tabbed webpart.

Comment: What issue are you facing with hillybilly tabs? I tried it on a blank webpart page and worked fine for me.

Comment: I have found a solution for my issue. I am writing a Blogpost about everthing and will post it here. Not only the link with a picutre, but the solution. Otherwise it might get downvoted again. Thanks for you help!